# How to distinguish the engine cooling flow and turbocharger air flow to/from radiator/intercooler?

Tags: engine, coolant, cooling-system, radiator

I can't distinguish between the flow of engine cooling (coolant) with the flow of turbocharger air to/from the radiator (intercooler?). I have no foundational knowledge of automotive/automobile, particularly the combution engines. Sorry, if the question makes no sense as it looks like I'm talking about liquid and air, like oranges and apples. It just i can't get the overall picture here. So I have a picture here describing the flow of coolant from/to engine like shown below

[image]

The red box part shown below should be connected/attached to the purple one.

[image]

That picture is talking about how the coolant (liquid) works. But if I see the picture below, suddenly the topic is about the turbocharger (air). I got confused.

[image]

[image]

I hope that someone can help me out to point out my misconception with regard to the topic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two radiators.

The first one closest to the front of the vehicle so it gets the coolest air is the air-to-air intercooler to reduce the tempersture of the compressed air from the turbo going to the engine.

Second will be the air-to-water radiator to keep the engine coolant cool.

The can also be the AC condenser which is usually first on many vehicles but then the first is always prone to stone damage…

Comment: And maybe a transmission radiator  ( my 2004 Titan had 3 radiators and none was for an intercooler).

Comment: @blacksmith37 had a car where I used the auto trans cooling coil in the engine radiator to heat diesel…

Comment: Hi thanks you're correct. Actually the cooling system consists of several layers. Mainly this speaks about the differences between intercooler vs radiator which is related to turbocharger vs non-turbocharger engines